# DocuSign simple button to connect account and get token

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am using sdk version and pretty much got what i want however this is not clear. how can we only connect a docusing account with one click like for example not using any forms or something. just a connect button and get the tokens and account details back using the sdk without any twig or symfony etc. any help would be gretaful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sounds like you may need to use [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/), not Auth Code Grant. With [Auth Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/) user needs to log in with user/password, but you want one click.

JWT requires you know/provide the **userId** of the user being connected. I recommend you try [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) and pick JWT and see that you can get it working first. Then, design your one button to do the same.